# How do I link my MSDN Azure Benefit to a specific Office 365 Tenancy

Tags: azure, office365

I have an MSDN 'Visual Studio Premium with MSDN' account.
I have created an Office 365 E3 Tenancy.
I have 'activated' Azure AD for that tenancy and can access the 'Access to Azure AD' subscription.
But this only gives me Azure AD and not all the other services.
How can I 'attach' my MSDN Azure benefit to this tenancy so that I can get all the other service options? Websites etc.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Sign in as your Office 365 administrator and go to this link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

when you sign up for an Azure Trial it will take you down the path you are aiming for.  Just make sure you select the options related to an MSDN subscription when they are presented.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. I signed in to the Azure Portal and then put in the link that you provided, I clicked on the MSDN Subscription link in purple at the bottom of the page. It then told me that this was only available to MSDN subscribers - it doesn't seem to link my MSDN account with this tenancy - there is no reason why it should because I have set it up anywhere. Perhaps that is the missing link - how do I associate my MSDN account with this tenancy?

Comment: maybe this will help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn736055.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to got manage.windowsazure.com and make the association there. There are instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment#bk_AssociateExistingAzureSubscription

Answer (score 0):

Hi there's an updated flow that will help make it easier to register for an app directly on dev.office.com.

You will still eventually need to go into Azure to manage and maintain the app, but if you're just getting started, you can do it in line at http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis.

The link from Michael will give instructions on registering the app through the Azure Portal as well.